# Is it possible to insert a fixed-size Input Cell in a DockedCell toolbar that directs output if any to a specified Cell in same Notebook?

Tags: functional-style, cells, output, menu, docked-cell

Ive been coding Mathematica for over a year but this language can do so much more than any other language hence beginners really do need a much longer *gestation* period. That is why this rarest of questions has no attempted code. I really don't know where to start or even if this concept is a good idea or even possible.

I've successfully programmed a few toolbars with `Button`-s for those menu items I use most often. More than a few of my peers have asked for my toolbar but each have asked for a few minor changes. It would be nice if I could give them a toolbar which has most items they require but is flexible enough to adapt to changing needs.

I envision a small regular `Input Cell` sitting in a `DockedCell` toolbar to use sort of like a "commandline" which would only be used for short native functions that manage notebook (`Quiet@Remove@{sym1,sym2,...}`, `$Line`, `$HistoryLength`, `etc`) or system wide tweaks. Even if this works there is a small problem though. How do we redirect output (in case of errors, or a misspelled Symbol, or or heavy output expected like in `$SystemInformation`) to a `Cell` specified with `CellTags` or if `Cell` does not exist output automatically sends it to the nth `Cell` in a `Notebook`?

Of course just about any function can be programmed in the main body of Notebook but that's no argument for opposing flexible toolbars. Some coders as myself are much more efficient when toolbars are available that are specifically suited to my current project. The other thing I dislike is dropping commands all over the notebook that have almost nothing to do with the application I'm coding. Cleanup should be programmed in or commands should have an alternate place.

I am not asking anyone to code anything but of course you may if you wish. If my idea is possible:

(1) I only need a ghost of a skeleton for key properties when they are different for a `DockedCell` containing an `Input Cell` along with Buttons. For example I dont need props or code for fixed-sizing my InputCell, just the minimum details needed to make it work.

(2) How to redirect output to an `Output Cell` identified with `CellTags` or by its `Position` in a Notebook if that tagged cell does not exist?